# how to create zip inside the other zip.i got the fileNotFoundException

Tags: java, file, structure, zip

How to create zip inside zip file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNA8b.jpg)

got bellow Error:

```
D:\sagar\my work\Package Maker\DirectoryStruct>java zipStructure
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Additional_Sub_Folder\Additional_file.zip (The sy
stem cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)
        at zipStructure.main(zipStructure.java:22)
```

`D:\sagar\my work\Package Maker\DirectoryStruct>`   that is Additional_sub_folder and Digital_sub_folder. inside Additional_sub_folder 1 zip file created(Additional_file.zip),inside that zip 2 folder are created like xml folder and pdf folder

and inside Digital_sub_folder create Artical_sub_folder,and inside Artical_sub_folder 3 new folder are created that is xml folder,pdf folder and Graphics folder. i try it be below java code but not works properly,please help to create the this structure.

```
    import java.io.*;
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.zip.*;
        import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
        import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

        public class zipStructure {

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("main.zip");
                ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
                zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("Additional_Sub_Folder/"));
                zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("Digital_Sub_Folder/"));


                FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream("Additional_Sub_Folder/Additional_file.zip");
                ZipOutputStream zos1 = new ZipOutputStream(fos1);
                /*zos1.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("Additional_file.zip/xml/"));
                zos1.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("Additional_file.zip/pdf/"));*/



                zos1.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("Additional_file1.zip/xml/"));
                zos1.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("Additional_file1.zip/pdf/"));

                    zos1.close();
                    fos1.close();

                    zos.close();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            public static void addToZipFile(String fileName, ZipOutputStream zos) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

                System.out.println("Writing '" + fileName + "' to zip file");

                File file = new File(fileName);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
                zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                    zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
                }

                zos.closeEntry();
                fis.close();
            }
            }


          [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNA8b.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the problem with the zip-I/O, I had the FileNotFoundException with every type of I/O that uses the fileSystem. 
What helped for me was, if you're **working with eclipse**, that there is function like "refresh project" or something like this. Everytime I had problems with I/O, that worked.

Comment: here i created folder and zip dynamically,but whenever i try to create Additional_file.zip inside Additional_Sub_Folder folder then i got that error ,please check the image which i provided ,thats structure i want.

Comment: not working with eclipse,i am try it on notepad and run through command prompt

Comment: the only thing i recognized now is that in fos1 you miss main.zip in the path...but i am not sure if it is required there.  FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream("MAIN1.zip???Additional_Sub_Folder/Additional_file.zip");

Comment: can you check provide image ,or said me are you create that structure my friend